# Create a subfolder on the Program Menu

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I created a Windows Installer (.msi) with Visual Studio 2017. I set up the File System on Target Machine as follows:

Application Folder

..... Primary output from my application

..... Documents

.......... User's Guide

.......... Version History

User's Desktop (Not currently using)

User's Programs Menu

..... Company Name

.......... Application Name

............... Shortcut to application

............... Shortcut to User's Guide

............... Shortcut to Version History

All 3 shortcuts are placed directly in the Company Name folder, not in the Application Name folder.  It doesn't appear as if subfolders are allowed on the Programs Menu because I went to the location of an already existing folder and created a subfolder.  The name that I created doesn't show up on the Program Menu.

My question is whether I am doing something wrong or if this is by design.  If it's by design, does anybody know why Visual Studio permits one to add a Folder when it can't be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of Windows (older ones) support folders in the Start menu (aka: `ProgramMenuFolder`). The new versions of Windows don't. Raymond Chen would remember when they changed their mind.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  Makes sense.  I am going to add shortcuts to the Program Menu.  It will accomplish the same thing